# regex match non white space characters except new line with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match the fifth column i.e ",,," and ",,,," and "," except new line i.e "\n" and then replace them with some value. the following is a file delimited by space . I tried following code:
Note: Though the example shows commas in the fifth column.It could be any characters (including tab \t) other than newline (\n).

```
my $delimiter="**";
my $dir_to_check=$DIR; 
opendir my $DIR, $dir_to_check or die "Error in opening dir '$dir_to_check' because: $!";
    my @files = readdir($DIR);
    closedir($DIR);
    foreach my $file (@files)
    {
            if($file =~ /\.fmt/)
            {
                unless ( open( CONTRL_FILE, "< $dir_to_check/$file" ) ) {
                    print "error while opening file $dir_to_check/$file \n"
                }   # UNLESS


               if ($file eq 'test.fmt')
               {
                    unless ( open( CONTRL_FILE_1, "> $dir_to_check/$file.temp" ) ) {
                    print "error while opening file $file \n"
                    }   # UNLESS
                    while(<CONTRL_FILE>)
                    {

                            $_ =~ s/"[^\s]+"/"$delimiter"/ ;
                            print CONTRL_FILE_1 $_;

                    }
                    close(CONTRL_FILE_1);
               }
            }
    }
```

Data:

```
1       SQLCHAR             0       5       ",,,"      1     ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       25      ",,,,"      2     ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       1       ","      3     ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","      4     ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\n"     5     ""
```

Result:

```
1       SQLCHAR             0       5       "*****"      1     ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       25      "*****"      2     ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       1       "*****"      3     ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       12      "*****"      4     ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       1       "*****"     5     ""
```

Expected Result :

```
1       SQLCHAR             0       5       "**"      1     ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       25      "**"      2     ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       1       "**"      3     ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       12      "**"      4     ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\n"     5     ""
```

Comment: Actually in the example above it is comma but it could be any combination of non white-space characters.

Comment: can you try: `perl -pe 's/(?<=")[^ \\]+(?=")/*****/g;' file` ?

Comment: Instead of `[^\s]+` use: `[^ \\]` to ignore `\n` as well

Comment: `^[^"\v]*?"\K((?!\\n)[^"\v]+)(?=")` using `m` modifier with `**` as substitution?

Comment: @k-five, that will ignore a 4th column containing just "\" in addition to "\n"

Comment: @arjun, actually "\n" in your data is a backslash and a n, so it is also a combination of non white-space characters.

Comment: @k-five, again, your regexp does not match a line such as `6       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\"     5     ""` or anything in quotes having one or more \ like `"stuff\"`- see: [there](https://regex101.com/r/uBU9an/1). Arjun says that 4th column "could be any combination of non white-space characters". Also, Arjun requires substitution to be `"**"`, not `"****"`. In fact, it is unclear what Arjun wants not to match because `\n` **is** a combination of non white-space characters. For instance, Arjun should clarify if `"a b"` or `"\t"` should match, so we know what he means.

Comment: @ctwheels solution worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of Perl then that may be a factor. In any case, I would suggest you make a minor modification ...

```
$_ =~ s/"[^\s"]+"/"$delimiter"/;
```

... that is a ", one or more NOT whitespace OR ", then a "

Comment: this will match the line `5       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\n"     5     ""` and that is not the wanted result

Comment: Tardis, perhaps you are looking at the problem differently? Please support your "will match" statement with an example. Mine follows...

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP says in his comment that the contents on 4th column could be "any combination of non white-space characters", and that he states that he does not want substitution to happen for the case when 4th column contains "\n" literally, I suggest he matches the contents of 4th column and then test, in two steps, whether what is in quotes includes a *literal* representation of what Perl would understand as a whitespace.

For doing that, we could use [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) or we could use a regexp with the [`ee` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Other-Modifiers), which is better and safer.

Here is an example using the latter (**update** - dataset correctly includes the OP's and additional cases):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $delimiter="**";

while (<DATA>) {
    # we capture the contents of the quotes in
    # 4th column, checking also the expected format
    if (/(^([^\s]+\s+){4})"([^"]+)"(.*)/) {
        my $st = $3;
        # "\n" in the file is actually "\\n" for Perl
        # so, to have Perl understand it as "\n", we need
        # to have Perl effectively escape it, we can
        # do that with a regexp and the ee modifier
        $st =~ s/\\([tnfr])/"qq{\\$1}"/gee;
        # now this will match an "\n", "\r", "\f" or "\t"
        if (!($st =~ /\s/)) {
            print "$1\"$delimiter\"$4\n";
        } else {
            print $_;
        }
    } else {
        print "error: wrong line format: $_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
1       SQLCHAR             0       5       ",,,"      1     ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       25      ",,,,"      2     ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       1       ","      3     ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","      4     ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\n"     5     ""
6       SQLCHAR             0       8       "a b"     6     ""
7       SQLCHAR             0       8       "\t"     7     ""
8       SQLCHAR             0       9       "\"     8     ""
9       SQLCHAR             0       9       "stuff\"     8     ""
```

which would result in:

```
1       SQLCHAR             0       5       "**"      1     ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       25      "**"      2     ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       1       "**"      3     ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       12      "**"      4     ""
5       SQLCHAR             0       1       "\n"     5     ""
6       SQLCHAR             0       8       "a b"     6     ""
7       SQLCHAR             0       8       "\t"     7     ""
8       SQLCHAR             0       9       "**"     8     ""
9       SQLCHAR             0       9       "**"     8     ""
```

Please note that there is no easy way to determine what a given script running on a given environment could understand as being a "[Perl whitespace](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Whitespace)", since it depends on many factors, and that `[\t\n\f\r ]` is just a simplified view of what Perl can understand as whitespace.

Quoting a bit of `perlrecharclass`:

> Whitespace
>
> \s matches any single character considered whitespace.
>
> If the /a modifier is in effect ...
>
> In all Perl versions, \s matches the 5 characters [\t\n\f\r ]; that is, the horizontal tab, the newline, the form feed, the carriage
>   return, and the space. Starting in Perl v5.18, it also matches the
>   vertical tab, \cK . See note 1 below for a discussion of this.
>   otherwise ...
>
> For code points above 255 ...
>
> \s matches exactly the code points above 255 shown with an "s" column in the table below.
>
> For code points below 256 ...
>
> if locale rules are in effect ...
>
> \s matches whatever the locale considers to be whitespace. (...)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\Ken>type test.pl

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl -w
$\="\n";
my $d="**";
my $L1="5 SQLCHAR 0 1 \",,,\" 5 \"\"";
my $L2="5 SQLCHAR 0 1 \"\n\" 5 \"\"";
foreach my $L ($L1,$L2)
{
  print "LineIn=$L";
  if ($L=~ s/"[^\s"]+"/"$d"/) {print "#YES L=$L";}
  else {print "#NO  L=$L";}
}
```

C:\Users\Ken>test.pl

```
LineIn=5 SQLCHAR 0 1 ",,," 5 ""
#YES L=5 SQLCHAR 0 1 "**" 5 ""
LineIn=5 SQLCHAR 0 1 "
" 5 ""
#NO  L=5 SQLCHAR 0 1 "
" 5 ""
```

Comment: Your example program is wrong because you attempt to use a Perl variable to define the data-set.The OP's data-set is in a file, which is being read by Perl, and that file contains "\n" literally in 4th colum of line 5, and thus when reading this file, the string obtained will contain there a slash and a n, and not a carriage return.

Comment: @argun I may have read your question incorrectly. When you state: _i.e ",,," and ",,,," and "," except new line i.e "\n"_ is \n a single character or two characters? Thanks!

Comment: @arjun, then your question seems to be as I understood it, and you may be interested in checking-out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320734/regex-match-non-white-space-characters-except-new-line-with-perl/46433282#46404223), to see if that does meet your needs. It would be nice that you provide some kind of feedback, since your question has really confused many contributors here, and you have only distributed information quite sparingly. I suggest you update your question to include the disseminated bits of information so it expresses clearer requirements.